# How to extract the first letter of certain words

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have an assignment that wants me to 'nickname' an input string. So far I was able to extract the first letter of every word in the string, but I need to exempt pronouns and words smaller than three characters.

This is what I have so far:

```
def nickname():
    name = input('Would you like to nickname a sentence or would you like to quit?: ')
    if name == "quit":
        print("bye")
    words = name.split()
    letters = [word[0] for word in words]
    return(" ".join(letters).upper())
```

Comment: `pronouns = {'i', 'me', 'you', ...}`, then use a conditional list comprehenson: `[word[0] for word in words] if len(word) > 2 and word.lower() not in pronouns]`

Comment: @Alexander If you're going to show the full solution, post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def nickname():
    name = input('Would you like to nickname a sentence or would you like to quit?:   ') 
    if name == "quit":
        print("bye")
    else:
      words = name.split()
      letters = [word[0] for word in words if len(word)>3]
      return("".join(letters).upper())

print(nickname())
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def nickname():
    name = input('Would you like to nickname a sentence or would you like to quit?: ')
    if name == "quit":
        print("bye")
    words = name.split()
    letters = [word for word in words if len(word)>3]
    return(" ".join(letters).upper())
```

Comment: `word[0]` - is inly first char, but your need to check `len(word)>3` and get `word`

Comment: he only wants the first char of each word that fits the criteria.